# How to handle libvlc exception in android?

Tags: android, libvlc

I had implement libvlc in my android application.as far it works great.But when the link is not available it returns the exception like this.

```
08-29 16:16:48.027 4923-4942/? E/VLC: core input: open of `https://archive.org/download/Popeye_forPresident/Popeye_forPresident_512kb.mp4' failed
08-29 16:16:48.027 4923-4942/? E/VLC: core input: Your input can't be opened
08-29 16:16:48.027 4923-4942/? E/VLC: core input: VLC is unable to open the MRL 'https://archive.org/download/Popeye_forPresident/Popeye_forPresident_512kb.mp4'. Check the log for details.
```

So Whenever i got this exception How did i show it in android?so i will create new player and it will repeat to stream.

This is my createPlayer() function:-

```
private void createPlayer(String media) {
    releasePlayer();
    try {
        // Create a new media player
        libvlc = LibVLC.getInstance();
        libvlc.setHardwareAcceleration(LibVLC.HW_ACCELERATION_FULL);
        libvlc.eventVideoPlayerActivityCreated(true);
        libvlc.setSubtitlesEncoding("");
        libvlc.setAout(LibVLC.AOUT_OPENSLES);
        libvlc.setTimeStretching(true);
        libvlc.setChroma("RV32");
        libvlc.setVerboseMode(true);
        LibVLC.restart(this);
        holder.setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBX_8888);
        holder.setKeepScreenOn(true);
        libvlc.playMRL(LibVLC.PathToURI(media));


    } catch (LibVlcException e) {// here I already have LibvlcException class in this library but still it didn't catch any exception.

        mSpinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Log.v("MyVlc", "Could not create Vlc Player");
    }
}
```